# Filling a DataGridView from SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++

I am trying to use the `DataGridView` to display my database data in to my form.

When I run the debugger on my code, after it hits the

```
da -> Fill(data);
```

line it throws an exception. I have used similar code before but the database was in MySQL and not SQL server. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code that I'm using

```
SqlCommand^ myCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyDatabase ;", myCon);

try{
    SqlDataAdapter ^ da = gcnew SqlDataAdapter();
    da -> SelectCommand = myCommand;
    DataTable^ data = gcnew DataTable();
    da -> Fill(data);
    BindingSource^ bSource = gcnew BindingSource();

    bSource -> DataSource = data;
    dataCustomer -> DataSource = bSource;
    da -> Update(data);
}
catch(Exception^ex){
    MessageBox::Show("Broke");
}
```

Comment: Whats the exception? Also in SQL Server you tend to query tables and not Databases which in SQL Server speak contain tables.

Comment: The exception that is thrown is Incorrect syntax near '289'. I am new to SQL Server and linking Database to front end projects. So I guess I am just trying to show a single tables data in the DataGridView. I have done this before using MYSQL and I used the about code with a slight variation.

Comment: This is related to your other query from before that you raised on another thread - "SELECT * FROM CSC 289.Customer WHERE Customer_ID = '"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to your other query from before that you raised on another thread [error C2664: 'System::String ^System::Data::Common::DbDataReader::GetString(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [12]' to 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689383/error-c2664-systemstring-systemdatacommondbdatareadergetstringint)

```
"SELECT * FROM CSC 289.Customer WHERE Customer_ID = '"
```

this is not a valid TSQL Statement as you can't have spaces in schema names. I think you want something like

```
SELECT * FROM [CSC 289].Customer
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [CSC 289].dbo.Customer
```

really depends on you database structure.

Comment: Oh ok. When I made the database I was not thanking about the spacing. So I just need to enclose the CSC 289 in []. Thanks so much that works great now.